# Which is best practice for Firebase storage file structure?

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, nosql

I want to store user's profile picture on Firebase storage.

My Firebase database structure is like below.

```
users
  ㄴ KXkVAYQOV92tW27Wk0C
       ㄴ uid: "EAGZwcgvgAcgErO7rfm7IHI91fk2"
       ㄴ sex: "F"
       ㄴ age: 24
  ㄴ KXkVR1rc2riXyGFl69E
       ㄴ uid: "alE4qM1vg2c9OrW5lVo7IvQk02Hv"
       ㄴ sex: "M"
       ㄴ age: 21
```

And now I'm wondering how my Firebase storage file structure should be.

**Idea 1:**

```
images
  ㄴ users
      ㄴ EAGZwcgvgAcgErO7rfm7IHI91fk2
           ㄴ profile.png
           ㄴ something.png
      ㄴ alE4qM1vg2c9OrW5lVo7IvQk02Hv
           ㄴ profile.png
           ㄴ something.png
```

**Idea 2:**

```
images
  ㄴ profile
      ㄴ EAGZwcgvgAcgErO7rfm7IHI91fk2.png
      ㄴ alE4qM1vg2c9OrW5lVo7IvQk02Hv.png
  ㄴ something
      ㄴ EAGZwcgvgAcgErO7rfm7IHI91fk2.png
      ㄴ alE4qM1vg2c9OrW5lVo7IvQk02Hv.png
```

Which one is best practice for Firebase storage in performance and usability?
Any advice would be thankful !

**Edit:**
As Lirianer's comment, Database should looks like below.

```
users
  ㄴ EAGZwcgvgAcgErO7rfm7IHI91fk2
       ㄴ sex: "F"
       ㄴ age: 24
  ㄴ alE4qM1vg2c9OrW5lVo7IvQk02Hv
       ㄴ sex: "M"
       ㄴ age: 21
```

Comment: What I tend to do is what you did in your "Idea 1" example, that way is easier for me to remember routes.
Also in the database I would use the uid as keys for the users and save the download path of the profile image as a string.

Comment: In my case, I'm storing images in Storage that are grouped under some node such as Root->ImageGroup1.

I upload the image to Storage and get the Storage URL back in onSuccess(). Then I write a structure to the Database using a model representing the image. The model contains two fields:  the URL of the image and the UUID of the user. I do a push() to get a key created and then setValue(imageModel) to write it to the database.

Comment: @Lirianer Thank you Lirianer, I agree with your opnion.

Comment: @Lucy Thank you. It was helpful advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. The idea 1 was suit for my case.